# How can I download the zip file directly to sd-card?

Tags: cyanogenmod

How can I download the CM 12 zip file directly to sd-card?

Answer (score 0):

You can Download the Cyanogenmod Zip file using any Web browser.

Locate the Downloaded file using File Manager App like (**Ex File Explorer** or  **Fx Explorer**)

Search for file using the search option in File Manager App.

If your File is in Internal Storage, Long Press and select the option **Move/Cut/Copy** to **Paste** into **SD Card**

If the File is already in **SD Card** then use the above steps to **Copy/Move** it to other folder.